# BDD - Test pass on chrome but not on Phantomjs

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, bdd

I have a web app built by Django, front-end is built by React. I tried to test bdd with behave and selenium. I run a test with Chrome web driver and phantomjs one but the tests only passed using chrome. I captured a screenshot when it runs on phantom and saw that the page is not fully rendered. Please give some suggestions about this issue. Do I need do further configuration to test with phantomjs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with PhantomJS (the page not being fully rendered), and often isn't something that can be remedied with explicit/implicit waits. Add a long (5 second) sleep to your code and take another screenshot.

If the page is fully rendered, follow @Alex Lucaci's instructions for adding (ideally) explicit waits.

If the page still isn't fully rendered, PhantomJS just wont work for you in this case. Personally, I would advise against using PhantomJS at all, as it is problematic in a myriad of ways, but also because why would you test on a browser that literally no one uses as their actual browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an explicit wait on a locator (waitForElementToBePresent) that exists on the part of page that is not rendered on Phantomjs.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options:

> implicitly_wait:

Implicitly wait means that the it will wait for a maximum of x seconds to search for an element so if you element will appear after 4 seconds you will get it when it will appear second if you set the implicitly wait greater than 4seconds.

Use `driver.implicitly_wait(x)` after creating the instance.

> explicitly_wait:

Explicitly wait means the it will wait for x seconds and it will search for the element after the seconds passed so if you set 10 seconds and the element will appear after 4 seconds the element will be located with 6 seconds delay.

Use `driver.explicitly_wait(x)` after creating the instance

> time.sleep

You can put your program to sleep and wait for the page to fully load after submitting some actions.

Use `time.sleep(x)` after submitting a form, clicking a button or loading a page.